# upload image and change source of an existing image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to upload an image and set the source of an existing image to that uploaded one
**image is uploaded**, but the new source doesn't work

```
<img class='avat' id='avat' src='ph/avat.jpg' alt='img'>
<input type='file' id='inpfile' accept=".jpg">
```

**js**

```
var imgavat = $('#avat');
var inpfile = $('#inpfile');
inpfile.on('change', function(){
    var uid = $('.aact').attr('data-id');
    var file = $(this).prop('files')[0];
    var form = new FormData();
    form.append('inpfile', file);
    form.append('uid', uid);
    $.ajax({
        url: "a_members_pro_plus.php",
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data); // avat/1.jpg - new source - ok
            imgavat.attr('src', data);  // doesn't work
            inpfile.val('');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the value for `data` in the response?

Comment: @RRK - `avat/1.jpg`

Comment: Do you have any other elements in the page with id `avat`?

Comment: @RRK - no, that's only one image on page - shortcut for avatar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) with [.readAsDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) in order to get a file and replace it with avatar.

When you select a file on your local computer with **inpfile** a change event is triggered.

In this event you need to test if there is one file (user selected a file):

```
this.files[0]
```

If the file exist you can instantiate the FileReader  (required for reading the file)  and add to it an handler for load end:

```
var reader  = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function () {
```

When the file is completely loaded you can change the attribute of your avatar:

```
imgavat.attr('src', reader.result);
```

In order to start this async process you need to read the file as a data url so you can update the avatar src image:

```
reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
```

The snippet:

```js
var imgavat = $('#avat');
var inpfile = $('#inpfile');
inpfile.on('change', function() {
    if (this.files[0]) {   
        var reader  = new FileReader();
        
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        
        reader.onloadend = function () {
            imgavat.attr('src', reader.result);
        };
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<img class='avat' id='avat' src='ph/avat.jpg' alt='img'>
<input type='file' id='inpfile' accept=".jpg">
```

Comment: could you explain, pls? where is the code for uploading image? I need it to be uploaded inside a specific folder. I tried to place your code inside the `success` part of my code and getting error

Comment: @yes, I see, thanks. It works now. Have you any idea why my previous code didn't work?

Comment: @qadenza  Write **//... code for uploading image** and I will take a look and so I can say you more...

Comment: pls see my post-update. this is the full js code. If you need the php code - no problem, but essentially it works - the uploaded image is there

Comment: @qadenza can you add the value of **console.log(data);**? thanks

Comment: console.log is `avat/1.jpg` - that's the path of uploaded image. I update the post

Comment: @qadenza Note: your default avatar src is "ph/avat.jpg" now it seems you cut off the **ph/**. Can be a problem related to the url??? Check it

Comment: that's ok - new and old src are different. Anyway - problem solved - thanks a lot for your time

Comment: @qadenza Thanks for sharing. I appreciate it a lot